# I got this error unable to access jarfile docker-compose

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run my application with docker using docker-compose.yml. I run 'docker compose up -d'. but it didn't work. when I checked the log, the error log is 'Error: Unable to access jarfile api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar'.
I have tried some other things. but the problem is still same.

Dockerfile

```
FROM gradle:jdk17-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /build

COPY build.gradle settings.gradle /build/

RUN gradle build -x test --parallel --continue > /dev/null 2>&1 || true

COPY . /build

RUN gradle build -x test --parallel


FROM openjdk:17-oracle

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /build/build/libs/api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  webserver:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    restart: always
    command: tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you show references a `api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` file name including a version; do you know where that name might come from?  The `volumes:` will overwrite the jar file in the image, which could cause a problem; does deleting that help?

Comment: I'm sorry.. I wrote wong on the Question. I already tried like that ```api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar```. but the problem is same..

Comment: comment the start  entrypoint command , and try to enter the container , make sure the jar has been placed in correct path , i guess that  the issue your encounter is that  you  are  read jar file from a invalid path